# Get lines from file per 60.000 and output them

Tags: python

I'm making a program that goes into a file (`outputs.txt`) and then outputs the file lines per 60.000 to a service called `throwbin`. So if there is 120.000 lines in the file I want it to give me two throwbin links.

This is my code

```
import requests

file = open("outputs.txt", 'r', encoding='utf8')

def get_tor_session():
    session = requests.session()
    session.proxies = {'http':  'socks5://127.0.0.1:9050',
                       'https': 'socks5://127.0.0.1:9050'}
    return session
get_tor_session()

def export():
    x = 0
    y = 60000
    line = file.readlines()
    session = get_tor_session()

    for i in range(x,y):
        lines = (line[x])
        x = x + 1
    y = y+60000
    throwbin = session.put("https://api.throwbin.io/v1/store",
                               data={"title": "test", "id": None, "paste": lines, "syntax": "text"})
    print("Throwbin link: https://throwbin.io/" + throwbin.json()['id'])

export()
```

This gives me a throwbin link with only 1 line from the file. I know what I did wrong I just have absolutely no clue on how I'd solve/fix this.

Comment: How many lines are there in the file?

Comment: there's 60k lines in the file

Comment: You're overwriting `lines` in each iteration of the loop.

Comment: @victorbrowser So why do you expect more than one link? You said it yourself: if there is 120.000 lines in the file I want it to give me two throwbin links. So 60.000 lines should give one link.

Comment: But the contents of the throwbin link is just 1 line from the text file (i want it to be 60k)

Comment: Is your indentation correct? There you should do 60.000 requests (using `session.put`)? Or you should send 1 put with 60.000 lines?

Comment: Get rid of the loop and do `lines = line[:60000]` for the first link and `lines = line[60000:]` for the second.